# Passing current Intent as extra to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a problem with my Login screen. When it's started, I check for network connection, and if it's disabled, I want to show NoNetworkActivity. And the same for every other screen: when Activity is launched, I check network connection and navigate to NoNetworkActivity is needed. When navigating, I want to save the Intent which launched this previous activity and finish it to disable the Back button redirection when on NoNetworkActivity. So, when connection is restored, I want to launch that intent and get actual state of the app before this error:

**LoginActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    if (!App.getInstance().isNetworkConnected()) {
        Intent noNetwork = new Intent(this, NoNetworkActivity.class);
        noNetwork.putExtra(NoNetworkActivity.EXTRA_FAILED_INTENT, getIntent());
        startActivity(noNetwork);
        finish();
    }
    ...
```

**NoNetworkActivity**

```
private void checkNetworkConnection() {
    mCheckButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (App.getInstance().isNetworkConnected()) {
        Intent failedIntent = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_FAILED_INTENT);
        startActivity(failedIntent);
        finish();
    } else {
        mCheckButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        App.toast("Connection failed");
    }
}
```

And it's getting strange: startActivity(failedIntent) does NOTHING. I've tried to remove finish() from next line, and NoNetworkActivity just stays on top without anything happening.

And one more thing. You can suggest passing Activity actual class names instead of intents, but I realy need Intent. That's because I'm using a lot of starting actions for every activity and a bunch of extras.

Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers!

Comment: which Activity you want to start from `NoNetworkActivity` ?

Comment: What is `App`? In your code you use things like `App.getInstance()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very bad approach. Don't use it.

First, you don't need to finish previous activity just to disable Back action. You can override `onBackPressed()`.

Second, you don't need to start parent activity again. Just call a new activity with `startActivityForResult();` and override `onActivityResult()` callback.

Third, but most important. Why do you want to call a new activity just to show 'No Network' message? And what if network won't be re-established? Just create `isNetworkEnabled()` method and call it when user attempts to get data from the Internet, before sending actual request to server. If no network - notify a user with an alert or toast.

Comment: 1) overriding `onBackPressed()`: finishing previous activity is better than clearing the whole task in NoNetworkActivity

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use fragments instead of activities first of all.
Using fragments you can set retainInstance(true);

To disable coming back from an activity to the previous :

1)call finish() on that activity

2)

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);`
```

Answer (score 0):

- It works with an explicit Intent.

In LoginActivity substitute:

```
noNetwork.putExtra(NoNetworkActivity.EXTRA_FAILED_INTENT, getIntent());
```

with:

```
noNetwork.putExtra(NoNetworkActivity.EXTRA_FAILED_INTENT, new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
```

Btw, Alexander Zhak has some good points in his answer